# Windows Fortran 64bit

Tags: compilation, fortran, 64-bit, windows-10, gnu

I am using the latest gfortran from MinGW and it seems I'm not getting my code compiled and run in 64bit. Is there a flag or compiler I should be using to take advantage of my 64bit version of Windows 10?

Comment: MinGW comes in both 32- and 64-bit targetted builds (the latter normally including -w64 in the name).  "latest" is meaningless as there are so many variants, some complying with licensing, some not.

Comment: Could you give me a link for the 64bit MinGW?

Comment: The gfortran wiki comes first in my search engine queries about this.  I prefer the one which comes on the cygwin  setup x86-64 install menu.  Others will have other preferences, including those which violate GPL.  As I said, your "the" is seriously off.

Comment: Okay. I got it! Thank you for your time